# All items in constraint layout move to top left

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-constraintlayout

In my emulator on Android Studio the layout looks as it should.  However, when I run it on my device, everything moves to the Top Left. This fragment launches as the login screen when a user is not signed in.

Thank you for any help.

The xml is below:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/LoginTitle"
    style="@style/LoginTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.15" />

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

    android:id="@+id/emailET"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="40dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.4">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="...."
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

....

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_rectangle_button"
    android:text="...."
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.75" />
```

Comment: please put full xml layout code not just part of it

Comment: if you use view.setvisibility(GONE) then, This problem will occurred.

Comment: @ABK,  I am not setting any views as gone.

Comment: match_parent doesn't supported by Constraintlayout. replace with 0dp.

Comment: @ABK Ok, I replaced it but it did not resolve the issue.  All items still in top left corner

Comment: Add FULL layout code. Of all compontents.